# What's HttpContext.Response.HasStarted for?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

For example, [`ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1d5b9218d7401e75e64b0dfca81b4e86100ebd21/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L136) uses this as:

```
if (context.Response.HasStarted ||...)
```

I don't quite get it. How can the web server start to send a response to clients when the request is still in the pipeline (assuming the `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` is the first middleware in the pipeline)? Because the request hasn't got out of `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`, it couldn't have arrived to the web server, so how could the web server already start sending responses to clients in this scenario?

Comment: _assuming the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware is the first middleware in the pipeline_: maybe this assumption is / can be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Any middleware or handler may choose to call [`WriteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponseWritingExtensions_WriteAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpResponse_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) (or other similar methods) on the `HttpResponse`, possibly multiple times.

It's not necessarily possible for all of those writes to just be stored in local buffers, and indeed may not be desirable to just buffer locally. So, sooner or later, those `Write` calls are going to result in real data being sent over the network.

And, in this concrete example, a handler may have made multiple calls such as the above before it encounters an error condition that causes control to be returned to the `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware`.

Answer (score 4):

Your specific `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` example uses [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse.HasStarted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.hasstarted):

> Gets a value indicating whether response headers have been sent to the client.

---

There is also [`Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.Response.HasStarted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.net.http.server.response.hasstarted):

> Indicates if the response status, reason, and headers are prepared to send and can no longer be modified. This is caused by the first write or flush to the response body.

Answer (score 1):

Each response consists of two parts: **Header** and **Body**

These two are sent together to the client: the **headers** first, then the **body**. So during development, the only opportunity to set any value on the response object that affects the headers is up to the point at which you start sending the body.

When you start sending the body of the response, you can no longer change the headers, because they are sent as the **first part** of the response, just before the body begins sending.